# How do I delete a random line in a text file from a given range?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, text-processing, text

I have a text file and I want to delete random lines from a range. Here is an example:

```
Line 1: abcd
Line 2: efgh
Line 3: ijkl
Line 4: mnop
Line 5: qrst
Line 6: uvwxyz
```

Out of these six, I want to randomly delete, say, 3.

How to get that done? It would be great if there is a solution in vim, so one can apply it on different ranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using `sed`:

```
sed -i $((start + RANDOM % range))d filename.txt
```

where:

- *start* is the beginning line number of your range
- *range* (or *end-start* is the number of lines to include from *start*)
- `sed -i -Nd` tells *sed* to delete line N in the input file
- `RANDOM` is bash's random number generator; a special shell variable that holds a random integer between 0 and 32767 when you use it.

So, for example, to delete a random line between lines 90 and 120 in file *test.txt*, you'd use:

```
sed -i $((90 + RANDOM % 30))d test.txt
```

Comment: Great! Almost there. Just three more points:

What if I want to delete multiple random lines at one go? Can I tell sed to delete say, m lines?

Can I tell sed to keep x number of line?

Lastly, if I want to execute the same command on a range in vim, :[range] !sed .... what should follow?

Comment: To delete a range N starting or ending at a random line, simply prefix `N,` or suffix `,N` to the `sed` expression. To delete multiple random lines, you can repeat the sed expression with `-e` i.e. `sed -e $... -e $... -e $...`. Keeping a certain number of lines seems difficult to do with a one-liner, but certainly with a bash script...

Comment: Please avoid using the `$[ ... ]` syntax. It has been deprecated for a decade and it was removed from the bash documentation ages ago. The only reason it still works is because of bash's policy on backward compatibility. `$(( ))` is the documented syntax for arithmetic expansion. `printf '%s\n' "$((90 + RANDOM % 30))d" w | ed -s file.txt`

Comment: OK. This was perfect. I have added an answer by putting everything together.

Comment: @geirha: many thanks for the edit. I missed your initial comment notification.

Comment: @izx I have similar problem. I need rows that having value greater than `36` in consecutive `7` columns . see my [data](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25783230/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete multiple random lines form a specific range in the text file, here is what I did:

- Open the file in vim
- Go to the top of the range from where you want to remove multiple random lines. The range should have an empty line at the bottom
- Enter the following command:

  ```
  .,/^\s*$/-1 !sed -e $((9 * $RANDOM / 32267))d
  ```

. - From here

,/^\s*$/-1 - Till the last non-blank line

!sed -e $((9 * $RANDOM / 32267))d - the sed command to delete a random line

That will delete one line at random.

Now, if you want to delete 5 more random lines, just do 5@: and vim does the rest.

This can be further improved if I can replace that 9 (number of lines from which to delete) with some expression that will be universal

Comment: bash only does integer math, so `$((9 * RANDOM / 32267))` will only result in 0 or 9. You really do need modulo. `$((RANDOM%9))`

Comment: Here's an awk that reads the input into an array, then prints all but one random line from the array. `!awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{srand();r=int(NR*rand())+1;for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)if(i\!=r)print a[i]}'`

Comment: @geirha Thanks! I will still use the same 4@: technique to delete multiple lines in vim. But I wonder how can I print all but 'n' random lines using awk

Comment: That's a bit more complex since you now have to keep track of what lines you've omitted already. Instead of making `r` an int we'll make it an array, and fill it with random numbers until it has *n* unique ones. `awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{srand();r[int(NR*rand())+1];while(length(r)<(n<NR?n:NR))r[int(NR*rand())+1];for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)if(\!(i in r))print a[i]}' n=2`  n=2 at the end says to omit two lines.

Comment: This gives an error, "awk: line 1: illegal reference to array r"


What could be happening here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot mawk's length() function only works on strings, not arrays. I only tested it with gawk. Is gawk (GNU awk) an option?

Comment: Sure, it was an option and that was perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
:nd
```

where n is the line number.

Comment: That would just delete a specific line. I want to delete a random line.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `python` as well:

```
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import sys,random;lines=sys.stdin.readlines();lines.pop(random.randint(0,len(lines)-1));print "".join(lines)' < input.txt
Line 1: abcd
Line 2: efgh
Line 3: ijkl
Line 5: qrst
Line 6: uvwxyz
```

The process here is simple, we redirect input file into python's `stdin` and read all lines into a list. Then we select random line index via `random.randint()` function within the range of all indexes in the list, from index 0 to last index ( that's what `len(lines)-1` does). That index is removed from list via `lines.pop()`, and we then print reassembled text. Quite simple